# I tried installing Kali Linux tools and my Ubuntu is messed up!

Tags: package-management, kali-linux-tools

I tried installing Kali Linux tools. I started installing some tools and there were several things I had to "agree" to and one message said `add users...` something in terminal, and when I came back I saw terminal reporting removing a bunch of core programs that I needed.

I canceled the process, but I don't know if I should reinstall Ubuntu or not.

How can I repair my system?

Answer (score 4):

Kali Linux tools are normally installed in Ubuntu by Katoolin, which  is a script that helps to install Kali Linux tools.

#### Warning about updates after installing Kali Linux tools

The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

[image: warning in terminal]

All kinds of problems can occur if you don't do this.

#### Undoing the changes that have been made by Katoolin.

1. All actions with `apt` are logged. These files are available in `/var/log/apt/`. To view the most recent history log run:

   ```
   less /var/log/apt/history.log
   ```

   This will show you the changes that you made installing Katoolin and Kali linux tools.
2. Copy these changes from `/var/log/apt/history.log` into a text file and save the file.
3. Undo all the changes that you made since installing Katoolin one by one. Take your time and check your work as you go to avoid making typing errors.
4. Remove Katoolin.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
5. **Important!** Look in your software sources for any repositories added by Katoolin and remove these repositories from your software sources. You are going to be reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop system in step 7, and if you don't remove all the software sources that were added by Katoolin it may interfere with step 7.

   Check what software sources have been added by Katoolin.

   ```
   cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep kali
   ```

   If you see a Kali software source, remove its `deb` and `deb-src` from `sources.list` and then save the file.

   Finish by manually checking your software sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and from the Dash by clicking on Software & Updates to open a Software & Updates window → *Other Software* tab to make sure that you removed all the software sources that were added by Katoolin.
6. Update the list of available software.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
7. If you are using Ubuntu, finish by reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop system.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```

When you have completed these steps, you may reboot the computer.