# Installing any package problem

Tags: package-management, nginx

does anyone knows whats problem? i didnt install nginx but when i try bellow command or apt-get upgrade or alot other things... it get error which seems to be about nginx!! my ubuntu is 18.04 and i joined it in active directory using sssd after a blackout i cant login with ad accounts and this problem started...also when blackout happened i was installing some packages with katoolin.

```
root@saeed-ubuntu:/etc# apt install jcal

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done jcal is already the newest version (0.4.1-2build1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 7 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Setting up nginx-core (1.14.0-0ubuntu1) ... Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed. ● nginx.service
- A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-08-06 12:36:27 +0430; 13ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)   Process: 20763 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 20758 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

آقۇست 06 12:36:24 saeed-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server... آقۇست 06 12:36:24 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) آقۇست 06 12:36:25 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) آقۇست 06 12:36:25 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) آقۇست 06 12:36:26 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to
0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) آقۇست 06 12:36:26 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) آقۇست 06 12:36:27 saeed-ubuntu nginx[20763]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind() آقۇست 06 12:36:27 saeed-ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 آقۇست 06 12:36:27 saeed-ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. آقۇست 06 12:36:27 saeed-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server. dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):  installed nginx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.8.2+dfsg-2) ... Checking smb.conf with testparm Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'secret and keytab' for parameter 'kerberos method' Error loading services. dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):  installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:  winbind depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.8.2+dfsg-2); however:   Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:  nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.1~) | nginx-full (<<
1.14.0-0ubuntu1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.1~); however:   Package nginx-core is not configured yet.   Package nginx-full is not installed.   Package nginx-light is not installed.   Package nginx-extras is not installed. nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-full (>=
1.14.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-light (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1); however:   Package nginx-core is not configured yet.   Package nginx-full is not installed.   Package nginx-light is not installed.   Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-winbind:amd64:  libpam-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind:any (= 2:4.8.2+dfsg-2); however:   Package winbind is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package libpam-winbind:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of set:  set depends on nginx; however:   Package nginx is not configured yet.   Package nginx-core which provides nginx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package set (--configure):  dependency problems
- leaving unconfigured No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-winbind:amd64:  libnss-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind:any (= 2:4.8.2+dfsg-2); however:   Package winbind is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-winbind:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:  nginx-core  samba-common-bin  winbind  nginx  libpam-winbind:amd64  set  libnss-winbind:amd64 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are you installing nginx beside apache ? It seems the port 80 is already used.

Comment: also cant even remove nginx

Comment: Try `dpkg -a --configure`

Comment: same error comes up

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/853584/help-i-tried-installing-kaltools-and-my-ubuntu-is-messed-up

Answer (score 5):

Try this sir,

```
sudo apt purge nginx*
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install nginx*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: The trick of adding * to nginx (making `sudo apt purge nginx*`) got me past being unable to purge.  Thank you for that!!   **BUT** `sudo init 6` is bad advice for anyone working remotely.  It broke SSH and I had to reboot in order to regain access.

Comment: What's your mean 'unable to purge', please what the error output said. I think The OP question isn't about ssh access

Comment: I mean that I would continue to get the error message `dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):  dependency problems`  when trying to do `sudo apt purge nginx`.  Adding the asterisk solved that.

Comment: On an **entirely separate point** - `sudo init 6` is bad advice for anyone working remotely. It broke SSH and I had to reboot in order to regain access.

Comment: That's mean you just purge nginx package and the dependencies. Not all of the nginx library package. Maybe yo're right i removed it

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common nginx-core*
```

Remove all nginx and keep only config files

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Remove any dependencies used by nginx

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Re-install Nginx.

Comment: while removing and re installing it i get almost same errors

Comment: should i also remove these:     samba-common-bin  winbind  nginx  libpam-winbind libnss-winbind