# Firefox not loading some sites

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, updates, firefox

Hello after the update and upgrade on my Ubuntu, the firefox is not loading specific websites like stackoverflow, askubuntu and such sites. It loads other sites like lichess.org and also able to play youtube videos. But on these sites the error is server not found. The same error that comes when you are not connected to the internet.

Now that's that I also have another problem which I don't know if related to this. When I do apt-get upgrade then it says http.kali.org not found. And on upgrade it says not secure to download.

It seems like the dns is messed up from the errors that it can't connect to any such websites. I don't have any proxy or any VPN or anything of that sort. Please help me. Sorry for just this plain html but I have to write this via my phone as my Ubuntu says nope.

Comment: I added kali tools in here a long time before.

Comment: OK so I can't have kali tools in Ubuntu or what?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/853584/help-i-tried-installing-kaltools-and-my-ubuntu-is-messed-up

Comment: OK I got this but why my firefox is not working on the specific sites?

Comment: Thank you for the answers but I switched to mint. My ubuntu was very very very much messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce mtu value (suggested 1452) instead of automatic for the specific wifi in ubuntu

or

reduce mtu in wan setup in router/modem

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate or give me a material to study. I am not able to understand what is mtu and why it's a problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: In UBUNTU settings -> wifi settings -> wifi connected name settings -> in the tab wifi there is a last option MTU.